# MySQL Delete Subsequent Duplicates

Tags: mysql

I know there is a lot of results that come up when you search this, but I can't find a simple, clear answer to what I am trying to to.

To make it simple, say I have a table with two columns:

'call_id' (pk, unique, auto increment) & 'guid'

I want to delete any rows with a duplicate guid, keeping just the first occurrence of each guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
delete c
    from calls c left join
         (select guid, min(call_id) as minci
          from calls
          group by guid
         ) cc
         on cc.minci = c.call_id
    where cc.minci is null;
```

Comment: Note that this will also delete all rows that have GUID column value of NULL. (That may be the behavior OP wants, but the specification didn't mention anything about it.) Do we consider NULL values of GUID to be "duplicates" of each other, or are they considered distinct?

Comment: Thanks. I would rather not delete nulls

Comment: Add a `where guid is not null` to the `delete`, if it is possible for a `guid` to be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff this worked. Hope it helps someone else looking for a solution too